# How can I control the number of Lazy Constraints in root node?

Tags: python, gurobi

I'm solving a Prize Collecting TSP and generating cuts to eliminate subtours. I want to generate cuts to eliminate disconnected subcycles (cut capacity = 0) and then, if there are no ones, generate 'min-cut' cuts (0 < cut capacity < 1).
The problem is that at some point, even having subcycles in which the cut capacity is less than 1, the program doesn't add more cuts at the root node.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from gurobipy import *

def ins_run(n, alpha, t=0):
    np.random.seed(t)

    depot = n + 1

    nodos = [i + 1 for i in range(depot)]
    pos = dict(zip([i for i in nodos],list(map(tuple,np.random.random([n, 2]) * 5))))
    pos[depot] = pos[1]

    c_cam = {(i, j): np.sqrt((pos[i][0] - pos[j][0]) ** 2 + (pos[i][1] - pos[j][1]) ** 2) 
             for i in nodos for j in nodos if i != j}

    c_drone = {e: alpha * c_cam[e] for e in c_cam}  # Velocidad del drone

    return pos, c_cam, c_drone

def delta_out(arcos, i):
    aux = list()
    for e in arcos:
        if e[0] == i:
            aux.append(e)
    return aux

def delta_in(arcos, i):
    aux = list()
    for e in arcos:
        if e[1] == i:
            aux.append(e)
    return aux

def delta_out_S(arcos, S):
    aux = list()
    for i in S:
        for e in delta_out(arcos, i):
            if e[1] not in S:
                aux.append(e)
    return aux

def run_DisconnectedCycle(G, nodos, capacity, peso):
    # Los arcos con valor no nulo tienen capacidad 1 y se determinan todos los subciclos desconectados
    G.remove_edges_from(list(G.edges))
    edges = list()
    for (i, j) in capacity:
        if capacity[i, j] > 1e-8:
            edges.append((i, j))
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    st_list = list(nx.simple_cycles(G))
    subtour_list = list()
    for i in st_list:
        if 1 not in i:
            peso_subtour = {j: peso[j] for j in i}
            subtour_list.append((i, max(peso_subtour, key=peso_subtour.get)))
    return subtour_list

def run_MinCut(G, nodos, capacity, peso):
    # Para todo j != depot, se hace min-cut. Sobre todos, se elige el subtour mas violado, junto al peso respectivo (gamma)
    G.remove_edges_from(list(G.edges))
    G.add_edges_from(capacity)
    for (i, j) in capacity:
        G[i][j]['capacity'] = capacity[i, j]
    subtour_list = list()
    subtour = None
    for j in nodos:
        if j != 1:
            (cap, (S, S_c)) = nx.minimum_cut(G, 1, j)
            if cap - peso[j] < 0:
                subtour_list.append((cap - peso[j], j, S_c))
    if subtour_list:
        subtour = min(subtour_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return subtour     


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def PCTSP_CB(m, where):
        def get_sol(model):
            x_sol = list()
            for e in index_2:
                arco_x = model.cbGetSolution([x[e]])
                if arco_x[0] > 0.5:
                    x_sol.append(e)
            return x_sol

        if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
            x_recurso = {e: 0 for e in index_2}
            x_sol = get_sol(m)
            for e in x_sol:
                x_recurso[e] = 1

            # SEC en solucion entera  
            G = nx.DiGraph(x_sol)
            subtour_list = list(nx.simple_cycles(G))
            for i in subtour_list:
                if 1 in i:
                    subtour_list.remove(i)
                    break

            for subtour in subtour_list:
                m.cbLazy(quicksum(x[e] for e in delta_out_S(index_2, subtour)) >= gamma[subtour[0]])
                cuts.SEC_int += 1

        elif where == GRB.Callback.MIPNODE:
            depth = m.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPNODE_NODCNT)
            if depth == 0:
                x_rec = m.cbGetNodeRel(x)
                gamma_rec = m.cbGetNodeRel(gamma)
                st_DisconnectedCycle = run_DisconnectedCycle(graph.G, nodos, x_rec, gamma_rec)
                st_MinCut = run_MinCut(graph.G, nodos, x_rec, gamma_rec)
                if st_DisconnectedCycle:
                    for subtour in st_DisconnectedCycle:
                        m.cbLazy(quicksum(x[e] for e in delta_out_S(index_2, subtour[0])) >= gamma[subtour[1]])
                        cuts.SEC_frac_DC += 1
                else:
                    # Si no hay subciclos desconectados, se agrega un Min-Cut
                    if st_MinCut:
                        m.cbLazy(quicksum(x[e] for e in delta_out_S(index_2, st_MinCut[2])) >= gamma[st_MinCut[1]])
                        cuts.SEC_frac_MC += 1

    class Graph():
        def __init__(self):
            self.G = nx.DiGraph()
            self.S_track = list()

    class Cuts():
        def __init__(self):
            self.SEC_frac_DC = 0
            self.SEC_frac_MC = 0
            self.SEC_int = 0

    # Data
    n = 30
    seed = 11
    alpha = 0.5
    pos, c, d = ins_run(n, alpha, seed)
    depot = n + 1
    nodos = [i + 1 for i in range(depot)]
    index_2 = [(i, j) for i in nodos for j in nodos if i != j]   
    graph = Graph()
    cuts = Cuts()

    model = Model()
#    model.Params.OutputFlag = 0
    model.Params.LazyConstraints = 1

    x = model.addVars(index_2, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='x')
    gamma = model.addVars(nodos, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, ub=1, name='z')

    model.addConstrs(quicksum(x[e] for e in delta_in(index_2, i)) == gamma[i] for i in nodos)
    model.addConstrs(quicksum(x[e] for e in delta_out(index_2, i)) == gamma[i] for i in nodos)
    model.addConstr(x[depot, 1] == 1)
    model.addConstr(x[1, depot] == 0)
    model.addConstr(gamma[1] == 1)
    model.addConstr(gamma[depot] == 1)

    model.addConstrs(x[e] <= quicksum(x[r] for r in delta_in(index_2, depot) if r[0] <= e[1]) for e in delta_out(index_2, 1)) 
    model.addConstr(quicksum(gamma[i] for i in nodos) >= round((len(nodos) - 1) / 2 + 0.1) + 1)

    obj = quicksum(x[e] * c[e] for e in index_2)

    model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

    model.optimize(PCTSP_CB)

    print(cuts.SEC_frac_DC, cuts.SEC_frac_MC)
```

Comment: Could you include a complete minimal code example to reproduce this?

Comment: I just updated it. Thank you.

Comment: I have looked at your code, but I am not sure I understand the issue. Your code adds lazy (subtour) constraints when a new solution is found (`MIPSOL`) and a different kind of lazy constraints when Gurobi is exploring the root node (`MIPNODE` and depth zero). This happens as often as a `MIPNODE` callback is called and you cannot control this. Maybe you need to go a bit deeper in the b&b tree. I also noticed that your third kind of lazy constraint (the one with `st_minCut`) is not added at the root node at all.

Comment: @SilkeHorn Thank you. Yes, and you can realize that even if `st_DisconnectedCycle` is not empty, the callback ignores the violated cut and skips the root node. What do you mean with going deeper in te b&b tree?

Comment: What do you mean with "the callback ignores the violated cut and skips the root node"? When I run the code, it adds disconnected cycle cuts every time the callback code is called in the root node. With going deeper, I meant that you could consider replacing `depth == 0` by something like `depth <= n` for `n > 0`. That way the code will be called more often and can add more constraints...

Comment: Because if I print a flag when it does not add a cut at the root node (in MIPSOL or MIPNODE), the flag should appear at the end (after solving the root node relaxation), but this does not happen.
I'm already getting the optimal solution to the problem, but I would like to know if Gurobi is effectively adding every cut at the root node.